# How can one approach a country manager after the application was delegated to a departmental manager but no timeframe was given?

Tags: recruiting

Would really appreciate your thoughts on this.
I emailed the USA country manager in regards to a supervisor position, which was advertised as 'Supervising the LA Region'. However, after emailing the US country manager to inquire about this position, he mentioned that this position is actually based in Hong Kong (Where the company headquarters is) due to cost management. The supervisors will therefore oversee the city from headquarters in Hong Kong.

However, the country manager said he will get in touch with the departmental manager (based in Hong Kong - but looks after the department I want to work for) in regards to a position locally based, where I oversee all local cities (e.g LA, NY, SF etc) as a local hired employee.

The country manager got back to me on Friday, and mentioned that the 'departmental manager' will reach out to me for a chat. He mentioned in the email to **keep him posted.**

I unfortunately haven't received any contact yet from the departmental manager, and want to know how long should I wait before I get back in touch.

There are two ways I can think of in regards to getting in touch:

a) emailing the country manager back and asking a timeframe/emailing the country manager (but I'm not sure how to word the email)

b) emailing the departmental manager directly - I have seen the departmental managers name on LinkedIn, and know the company email format so I could send him an email directly. But I was thinking it would seem really rude emailing out of the blue?

Would really appreciate your advice, I'm really stuck on what to write in an email so pointers would be much appreciated.

NB: Not a duplicate to other questions already asked, as the application was delegated to another manager and no timeframe was given.

Answer (score 1):

The country manager asked you to keep him posted. Assuming you got the email from the country manager last Friday then I think waiting a week is sufficient. I'd reach out to the country manager via email this Friday and let them know that you haven't heard from the department manager yet.

"Just checking in as I haven't yet heard from the department manager. Is the position we spoke about still under consideration? Do you have a time frame for when you'll be moving forward with this? Thank you."

Comment: Thank you Joe for your prompt reply!  Yes, correct - the country manager was the one who wrote the email last Friday.  Thank you again

Comment: Would it be wise however, to ask the country manager for the departmental managers email (e.g 'Would you like me to send an email to the departmental manager in regards to this to assist with the process'?)  - You can probably word it better than me!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest it. The country manager seems to be the person who is driving this process, so let them drive it. Let them be the one to either reach out to the department manager and tell them to contact you, or to tell you that they've decided to go in a different direction. The department manager probably has no "power" to affect any progress without the country manager's direction.

Comment: If the country manager wants to hire you then they'll make it happen and they'll direct the department manager to make it happen. If the country manager has decided against it then your contacting the department manager will get you nowhere.

Comment: Thank you!  Fingers crossed it all works out many thanks!